# Is "benefict" a correct version of "benefit"?

Tags: vocabulary

I heard a friend saying "benefict". I am not a native English speaker, but I know the correct word is "benefit". Am I wrong? He could have used "gain". I have searched in dictionaries and apparently I have found "benefict" in one.

Comment: You might want to Google **benefice** (a church appointment) as yet another spelling of the word. It is, as far as I know, the only use of this version. See also the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefice)

Answer (score 3):

*Benefict* is an obsolete (and I think very rare) spelling if *benefit*. The OED lists it as a spelling from the 1600s, but gives no examples of it.

I have never heard anybody say it.

The person you heard is either mistaken, or deliberately using an almost unrecorded obsolete form of the word.

And you're right that in many contexts *benefit* means the same as *gain*, but they are not always interchangeable.

Comment: Now I think about it, I doubt that anybody ever pronounced it "-fict". That spelling was a scholarly one that happened to a number of words around then. In that one it didn't stick. In _debt_ the 'b' did stick, but has never been pronounced. In _perfect_ the 'c' not only stuck, but eventually came to be pronounced as well.